# Double integral in cartesian space

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the integral $$S = \int _0 ^1 \int _\sqrt{x-x^2} ^\sqrt{ax-x^2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dydx,$$
where $a$ is a real number.

Express the value of S in terms of $a$.

My current problem is I am not sure how to change the upper and lower limits if I were to change the $x$ and $y$ to polar coordinates, $r$ and $\theta$. Anyway you can use whatever methods you like!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice is that that the limits if integration describe two circles. Notice that the restriction on $x-x^2\leq y^2\leq ax-x^2$ describes the area between two circles (let's call them $C_1$ and $C_2$):

$$C_1:\, y^2+(x-1/2)^2=1/4, \quad C_2:\,  y^2+(x-a/2)^2=a/4$$

Notice that $C_1$ has radius $1/2$ and is centered in $(0,1/2)$, while $C_2$ is centered in $a/2$ and has radius $a/2$. Now, we recur to polar coordinates:

$$x=r\cos\theta,\quad y=r\sin\theta$$

And therefore the integral to be solved is:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{1/2}^{a/2}r^2drd\theta$$

Notice that I have implicitly assumed that $a>1$, and that the smaller circle never intersects the bigger one. You should think about whether this makes sense with the help of a graph.